# Django 1.6.5 - "invalid literal for int() with base 10" in regirstration form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-registration

I'm trying to implement a registration form but I get the following error:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10:'alex'

I implemented it before and it worked well! But now it does not! My form contains an 'ImageField' and I followed the [this](https://coderwall.com/p/bz0sng) and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files) docs and tutorials. I removed the `Imagefield` but the error remained! I read the similar question on SO but They didn't solve the problem.

The error occurs in the `username` field.

thanks for any comments.

my `form.py` is:

```
class RegisterationForm(ModelForm):
    # user name
    user_name = forms.CharField(max_length=32, label="Username account")
    # password
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    re_password = forms.CharField(label='Repeat Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    # email
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email Address')

    class Meta:
        model = WebsiteUser
        exclude = ('user', )

    def clean_user_name(self):
        user_name = self.cleaned_data['user_name']
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=user_name)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return user_name
        raise forms.ValidationError(u'UserName Error')


    def clean(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['re_password']
        if password != password1:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Passwords are not equal')
        return self.cleaned_data
```

and my `view.py` responsible for my `register.html`:

```
def register_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['user_name'],
                                            password=form.cleaned_data['password'],
                                            email=form.cleaned_data['email'])
            user.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
        else:
            return render_to_response('register.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = RegisterationForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render_to_response('register.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and finally my `register.html`:

```
{% extends 'bases/home_base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if form.errors %}
            <p>
                Fix the errors!
            </p>
        {% endif %}
        <div id="register_div">    
            {% comment %} User Name {% endcomment %}
            {% if form.user_name.errors %}<p>{{ form.user_name.error_messages }}</p>{% endif %}
            <p><label for="user_name">User Name:</label></p>

            <p>{{ form.user_name }}</p>


            {% comment %} password {% endcomment %}
            {% if form.password.errors %}<p>{{ form.password.error_messages }}</p>{% endif %}
            <p><label for="password">password:</label></p>

            <p>{{ form.password }}</p>

            {% comment %} re_password {% endcomment %}
            {% if form.re_password.errors %}<p>{{ form.re_password.error_messages }}</p>{% endif %}
            <p><label for="re_password">re_password:</label></p>

            <p>{{ form.re_password }}</p>

            {% comment %} email {% endcomment %}
            {% if form.email.errors %}<p>{{ form.email.error_messages }}</p>{% endif %}
            <p><label for="email">email:</label></p>

            <p>{{ form.email }}</p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

**UPDATE**

my `model.py`:

```
class WebsiteUser(models.Model):
    # username
    user_name = models.OneToOneField(User, max_length=32)
    # birth day
    birth_day = models.DateField()
    # email address
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    # watched movies
    watched_movies = models.ManyToManyField(Movie, related_name='watched', blank=True, null=True)
    # rated movies
    rated_movies = models.ManyToManyField(Movie, related_name='rated', blank=True, null=True)
    # recent movies
    recent_movies = []

    def __unicode__(self):
        return " ".join([self.first_name, self.last_name])
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/

Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'movie_app',
 'person_app',
 'home_app',
 'social_auth',
 'website_user')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\Programming\Django\DBMI_Final\website_user\views.py" in register_view
  15.         if form.is_valid():
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  129.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  121.             self.full_clean()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  275.         self._post_clean()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in _post_clean
  413.                 validate_unique=False)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in full_clean
  928.             self.clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in clean_fields
  970.                 setattr(self, f.attname, f.clean(raw_value, self))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in clean
  255.         self.validate(value, model_instance)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in validate
  1203.                 **{self.rel.field_name: value}
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  593.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  611.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1204.         clause = self._add_q(where_part, used_aliases)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1240.                     current_negated=current_negated)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1131.         clause.add(constraint, AND)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\tree.py" in add
  104.         data = self._prepare_data(data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py" in _prepare_data
  79.             value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py" in prepare
  352.             return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  369.             return self.get_prep_value(value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  613.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /register/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'alex'
```

Comment: Suggest posting the line causing the error and a stack trace.

Comment: You should at least specify where is the error.

Comment: Could we also see the model for the User object, please?

Answer (score 3):

`WebsiteUser.user_name` is `OneToOneField`, thus it stores a value of primary key of the related object. You're trying to store a username there instead, that won't work.

Comment: the problem is with my form validation!

Comment: so what?! `user_name` is ForeignKey, that means it's an integer field in DB. So if you validate your **ModelForm** then it validates it against the model, not the type you say in form.